# Parameters from AJAX call to C# controller mapped differently on different machines

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax

I am using jquery ajax to make a call to C# controller's method and here is the controllers method:

```
public ActionResult AddRegion(string pageIdIn, string fieldIdIn, RegionMV regionMv)
        {
            var fieldRegFormDataOutMv = batchLogic.AddRegion(Session.SessionID, pageIdIn, fieldIdIn, regionMv);
            var json = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(fieldRegFormDataOutMv);
            return Json(json, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Here is the ajax call code:

```
function AjaxWrapper(param, url, success, failure, deferred, args) {
       return $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: param,
            // contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            //dataType: "json",
            success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                success(data, args); 
                deferred.resolve();
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                // //! call the function that will pop a div in the view to tell the user something went wrong - > failure(response);
                failure(textStatus);
                console.log(jqXHR);
                deferred.reject();
            },
            cache: false
        });
    }
```

And here is the code that calls the ajax method:

```
function addRegion(pageId, fieldId, region) {
    var param = { pageIdIn: pageId, fieldIdIn: fieldId, regionMv: region };
    var deferred = $.Deferred();
    showProgress();
    AjaxWrapper(param, window.urlsList.addRegionUrl, updateView, showError, deferred).done(function () {
        hideProgress();
    });
    return deferred.promise();
}
```

The problem is that on my computer(using Windows 7) the region json is being mapped to a RegionMV object correctly(with all properties and a correct bounding box), but on another computer(using Windows 10) the region's properties are mapped correctly except the bounding box.
Here is the class RegionMV:

```
public class RegionMV
    {
        // Index of the region in the parent page
        public string Id { get; set; }

        // Region type
        public RegionType Type { get; set; }

        // Region bounding box
        public RectMV BoundingRect { get; set; }

        // Region confidence as a specific field (determined by the 'Name' property)
        public int FieldConfidence { get; set; }

        // Region name (filled for regions assigned to specific fields or cells)
        public string Name { get; set; }

        // Region text content
        public string Content { get; set; }

        // Region text content filtered as specific field (determined by the 'Name' property) value 
        public string ContentFiltered { get; set; }
    }
```

Any ideas why is that happening? Is it because of the different operational systems(I kind of doubt that, but still?) or because of something else?
**EDIT!**
Here is my RectMV class:

```
public class RectMV
    {

        public double X { get; set; }
        public double Y { get; set; }
        public double Width { get; set; }
        public double Height { get; set; }
}
```

And the Chrome Versions are the same on both machines.

Comment: post your c# `RectMV` model

Comment: different browser version? Report the exact environment, and it might also be useful to show the differences in the serialised data.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is your issue, but I recently ran into trouble when posting data with `$.ajax()` where the request body was not being sent as JSON even with the content type explicitly set as `"application/json"` on Windows 10 Chrome 58

Comment: have you tried any other browsers? Might be a useful test to understand whether it's a browser issue, or something in the code.